# sql to grab results that have a date 3 days away

Tags: php, mysql

I have this SQL query that is suppose to grab all the results from 3 days from today.... but I'm not sure if the timestamp it's using to compare have to match exactly, or if they way I have written grabs any post from any hour on that day. Here's what I have:

```
SELECT * from wptb_clinic WHERE DATE(clinic_date) IN (DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

`clinic_date` would be the timestamp saved in the table `wptb_clinic`. And then the rest is something I got of stackoverflow.... this is for a cron job that is set to once a day and send out a reminder email to all clinics that match... so `CURDATE()` would be different each time.

Here's a sqlfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a1dc1/2

I added the dates for today tomorrow and the day after tomorrow. so it should find one

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: added the sqlfiddle, thanks for the heads up

Comment: 3 days from today or before today?

Comment: i switched it out in the sqlfiddle to 1 day from today, so tomorrow. But once i get this one working, im going to do seperate ones to send out email reminders 3 days fom today, and 7 days from today

Answer (score 0):

3 days in the future, would be

```
select  now()  + INTERVAL 3 day
```

In case you want 3 days in the future but in 0:00 (midnight)

```
select  date(now()  + INTERVAL 3 day)
```

So your query will probably look like:

```
SELECT * from wptb_clinic WHERE clinic_date > date(now()  + INTERVAL 3 day)
```

Here is how you can test it. You need to use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` if you want to use integers. You can always use dates such "2015-06-25".

```
CREATE TABLE Clinics(
   `id` int, 
   `Name` varchar(250), 
   `date` timestamp
);

INSERT INTO Clinics
    (`id`, `Name`, `date`)
VALUES
    (1, 'clinic1', FROM_UNIXTIME(1456444800)),
    (2, 'clinic2', FROM_UNIXTIME(1456531200)),
    (3, 'clinic3', FROM_UNIXTIME(1456617600));

SELECT *
FROM Clinics
WHERE DATE(date) > (DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY));
```

Comment: This should work. Heres a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a1dc1/4 (But im not sure if the date values you added there are actually in the future)

Comment: sorry i changed it to 1 day from today instead of 3, but the dates added in the db are of today, tomorrow and the day after tomorrow.... i changed the sqlfiddle you linked too 1 day but it still didnt work.

Comment: same, change 3 day to 1 day

Comment: wouldnt this sql using > mean more than get everything that is more than the date? i need the email reminders to get sent out 1 day before. aswell as 3 days, 7, days etc, but all in their own seperate sql execution

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a1dc1/6 edited to 1 day, still doesnt work, even though technicaly it should show results properly for either 1 day or 2 days with the current records

Comment: also note date(`date`) "truncate" time. It depends what you want to do.

Comment: hmm, just tested it out changing the time interval to 2 days from today, which should grab clinic3, but it only seems to work for clinic2 which is 1 day away.... im hoping to make sure it works everytime, it should grab all results from that 1 day no matter the hour or minute of the day the chron job executes. Its a wp_chron job, so it shoots with the first person that visits the site that day.

Comment: you need >= instead of >

Comment: hi nick, still not working for me.  is there no way to make this work just using normal timestamps, not the sql timestamps that are formated like 0000-00-00 00:00:00